# Adding Mobfox to AdWhirl rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, adwhirl

I want to have Mobfox in my AdWhirl rotation but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this, I know that Mobfox is unsupported with AdWhirl. Any one got any experience with this? I'm an iPhone developer.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to do this! check out this post:

[Combining MobFox/AdWhirl on iOS](http://blog.mobfox.com/2011/07/06/combining-mobfoxadwhirl-on-ios/)

hope this helps